# How to let mkString skip null in scala?

Tags: scala

```
scala> Seq("abc", null).mkString(" ")
res0: String = abc null
```

but I want to get "abc" only

Is there a scala way to skip nulls?

Comment: As the old joke goes, "Doctor, doctor, it hurts when I do this."  "So, don't do that."  Use `Option[String]` as your type, and `None` instead of `null`.

Comment: I'd love to do so but these nulls come from Java code. Is this better: Seq(Option("abc"), Option(null)).flatMap(s => s).mkString(" ")?

Comment: Try it that way, then by filtering, then by changing the Java code.  See which is faster while remaining correct.

Comment: @NSF, `flatMap(s=>s)` can be written more succinctly as `flatten`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
scala> val seq = Seq("abc", null, "def")
seq: Seq[String] = List(abc, null, def)

scala> seq.flatMap(Option[String]).mkString(" ")
res0: String = abc def
```

Comment: +1 for the `flatMap` approach. This is what I would expect out of idiomatic Scala. It's also good to know that Option(null) reliably returns "None"

Answer (score 15):

There's always `Seq("abc", null).filter(_ != null).mkString(" ")`

Comment: `Seq("abc", null).iterator.filter(_ != null).mkString(" ")` to avoid building the intermediate collection.

Comment: @KevinWright Current versions of Scala have `withFilter` for that, don't they? **Update**: Just tried it - apparently `mkString` doesn't work directly with `withFilter`

Answer (score 1):

Combination of Rex's answer and Eric's first comment:

```
Seq("abc", null).map(Option(_)).collect{case Some(x) => x}.mkString(" ")
```

The first `map` wraps the values resulting in `Seq[Option[String]]`. `collect` then essentially does a `filter` and `map`, discarding the `None` values and leaving only the unwrapped `Some` values.

Comment: `Seq("abc", null).flatMap(Option(_)).mkString(" ")`.  Flatten does what you want it to.